# Shared memory and waiting sessions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, unix, parallel-processing, shared-memory, wait

Doing a regression on a large dataset, I have a huge read-only matrix that I'd like to share among several threads. I've looked at various way of doing this and found [`sharedmatrix`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28572-sharedmatrix) toolkit to be exactly what I need. Reading through the [tutorial](http://smlv.cc.gatech.edu/2010/08/27/shared-memory-in-matlab/), I came up with the following setup:

- `Session 0` - just loads up the matrix and makes it available
- `Session 1..n` - worker sessions

The problem is that `Session 0` has to finish only after all the other n sessions have finished. Do you know how to make a session wait? The best solution would be to make it wait until I kill it as I'm running the scripts on a remote linux system and am not connected to it all the time.

**UPDATE:**
In the end I've changed my approach to the problem, after reading this part of the tutorial:

> The “free” directive marks the shared memory segment for deletion.
>   Note: it is not actually deleted until every attached session
>   explicitly detaches or is terminated. As soon as the last session
>   detaches, the system will reclaim the allocated segment.

This means that I've created one "master" session that loads up the matrix, makes it available and then starts its own computation, and several "slave" sessions that use the shared matrix. Even if the master session finishes earlier, it causes no problem to the slave sessions as the shared matrix remains in the memory until the last process that uses it is terminated.

Comment: Maybe waiting for a the user to press a key (with `pause` for example)  would suffice?

Comment: If you really want to have it wait indefinitely, use Eitan's solution. More generally, something like [`labBarrier`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/labbarrier.html) is what you should use to perform this kind of synchronization.

Comment: @JoshuaBarr Your comment is a great answer. Why not submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to have it wait indefinitely, use Eitan's solution based on [`pause`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html). More generally, something like [`labBarrier`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/labbarrier.html) is what you should use to perform this kind of synchronization.